# Failing on errors inside a function which is called on the left-hand-side of an && expression

Tags: bash, error-handling, trap, bash-functions

I am working on a Bash script with several functions. I would like to exit the script if any commands return an nonzero exit code, unless in a context where that code is being explicitly handled (such as in an `if` condition or before a `||` alternative). To make this easier, I have removed all use of sub-shells from my script, and enabled every error handling option I could find.

Unfortunately, I'm still encountering a common pattern where errors are being suppressed.

If a command in a function returns a nonzero exit code, but is not the last command in the function, and the function is being called as the first part of an `&&` expression, the exit code is ignored.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Error occurred." && exit' ERR
set -o errexit;  # -e
set -o errtrace; # -E
set -o pipefail;

first-step-fails() {
    # These should be redundant, but are repeated to be certain and clear.
    trap 'echo "Error occurred." && exit' ERR
    set -o errexit;  # -e
    set -o errtrace; # -E
    set -o pipefail;

    false; # exit code 1 (failure)
    true;  # exit code 0 (success)

    echo "A is executed.";
}

first-step-fails && echo "B is executed.";
```

```
A is executed.
B is executed.
```

I didn't expect either `echo`s to be executed following the call to `false`.

---

If the function isn't called in a `&&` expression, the error is trapped:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Error occurred." && exit' ERR
set -o errexit;  # -e
set -o errtrace; # -E
set -o pipefail;

first-step-fails() {
    # These should be redundant, but are repeated to be certain and clear.
    trap 'echo "Error occurred." && exit' ERR
    set -o errexit;  # -e
    set -o errtrace; # -E
    set -o pipefail;

    false; # exit code 1 (failure)
    true;  # exit code 0 (success)
    echo "A is executed.";
}

first-step-fails ### && echo "B is executed.";
```

```
Error occurred.
```

If the failure is the last step in the function, the error isn't trapped but of course the function passes on its nonzero exit status and suppresses the outer `echo`.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Error occurred." && exit' ERR
set -o errexit;  # -e
set -o errtrace; # -E
set -o pipefail;

first-step-fails() {
    # These should be redundant, but are repeated to be certain and clear.
    trap 'echo "Error occurred." && exit' ERR
    set -o errexit;  # -e
    set -o errtrace; # -E
    set -o pipefail;

    false; # exit code 1 (failure)
    ### true;  # exit code 0 (success)
    ### echo "A is executed.";
}

first-step-fails && echo "B is executed.";
```

```
(no output)
```

---

How can I have my bash script exit when there's an nonzero exit status returned from a command called inside a function that's invoked on the left-hand-side of an `&&` expression?

I have been testing on macOS (built-in GNU Bash 4.4.23) but need a solution that also works on Alpine Linux (packaged GNU Bash 4.4.19).

Comment: related reading: [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), ["set -e" in various shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/), [Bash: Error handling](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as if this description of `set -e`:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is ... part of any command executed in a && or || list

is liberally interpreting "part of a && list" to include every command within the function call. As a result, even a simple failing command inside the function does not trigger the ERR trap -- when it is called in an `&&` chain.

If you need to stop execution of the function's commands when one of them fails, one possibility would be to chain them all within a block:

```
first-step-fails() {
    { 
      true &&
      false &&
      true;
    } || exit 1

    echo "A is executed.";
}

first-step-fails && echo "B is executed.";
```

... results in no output and a return-code of 1.

Comment: Darn. Okay, explicit and verbose it shall be. Thanks.

Comment: Would be good to now if "'is liberally interpreting" is true or if this is in fact POSIX's requirement.